# In python want to read the UDP broadcast message on particular port

Tags: python

I am new to python programming. I have the task to read the broadcast feed on UDP port 4012.I have code of visual basic and it is working fine. The code is as follows.

```
#Dim receivingUdpClient As New UdpClient(4012)
#Dim RemoteIpEndPoint As New IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, 0)
#receiveBytes = receivingUdpClient.Receive(RemoteIpEndPoint)
#returnData = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveBytes)
#Dim TestArray() As String = Split(returnData, ";")
```

I made the following program in python to read the broadcast feed on UPD port 4012, but was unable to achieve it with the following python program. The program is working and shows the cmd window message "waiting for 4012 localhost from 4012".

Can anybody help me out with this? If the code is correct then, how can i checked resolve this issue?  i also want to read good material about socket programming in python specially about the UDP socket Broad Cast reading, if anybody can recommend any video or material for read.

```
import socket

s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
udp_host = 'localhost'
udp_port = 4012

s.connect((udp_host,udp_port))
print("waiting for 4012",udp_host, "from" ,udp_port)
data , addr= s.recvfrom(1024)
print("Received Messages: ", data ,"from", addr)
```

Answer (score 2):

You should use broadcast IP to listen.
Currently you are listening 'localhost', but broadcast IP is usually your subnet maximum IP (for 255.255.255.0 mask it is IP with number 255 in last octet)

You need to get right IP from somewhere. Manually you can do it with `ifconfig` on *nix, or `ipconfig` on Win:

`inet 192.168.100.7 netmask 0xffffff00 broadcast 192.168.100.255`
so you need `192.168.100.255`

Also, easy way is to listen *all* IP's. To listen all IP's you could bind socket to `'0.0.0.0'` or just `''`. But in this case you'll catch both broadcast and direct packets.

```
import socket

s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
udp_host = ''
udp_port = 4012

s.connect((udp_host,udp_port))
print("waiting for 4012",udp_host, "from" ,udp_port)
data , addr= s.recvfrom(1024)
print("Received Messages: ", data ,"from", addr)
```

Answer (score 0):

this snippet is something i use quite often do create basic socket server stuff...

```
 socket_config = {
        'udp_ip_address': 'your.ip.here.bla',
        'udp_port_no':    '6789',
        'max_send_size':  '1024'
    }
    #
    # socket creation
    #
    serverSock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_DGRAM)
    serverSock.bind((socket_config['udp_ip_address'],
                    int(socket_config['udp_port_no'])))
    
    def receive_loop():
    
        # eternal loop starts here
      while True:
        data, addr = serverSock.recvfrom(int(socket_config['max_send_size']))
        data = data.decode('utf-8')
        logger.debug("Message:" + data)
```

Comment: It does not answer this question. Author asked about broadcast messages receiving

Comment: I will try the solution of Pavel Shishmarev. It look to me will work. Thanks you very much